# Parsing Error - Else

Tags: python, parsing, if-statement, syntax

I can't seem to figure out why there is a parsing error on "else:" in this python code. Please help.
I am trying to count the number of times the same 'email' appeared using dictionary from the text "mbox-short.txt". The final result should print the key (that is the email) and the value (number of times repeated).

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
try:
    handle = open(name)
except:
    print 'Invalid input.'
    quit()

def emailrepeat(s):

    d = dict()

    if s not in d:
        d[s] = 1
    else:
        try:
            d[s] = d[s] + 1
        except:
            print "error"

    return d


for line in handle:
    if line.startswith('From:') == True:
        continue

    if line.startswith('From') == True:
        newline = line.split()
        email = newline[1]
        print email

        print emailrepeat(email)
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Are the asterisks around the else part of your code? If not I would remove them and indicate the Problem Location with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

What the `**else**` mean?

[image]

If your want note the else statement, please use the `#` or `'''`.

[image]

Comment: this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

remove the asterisk around else, to make else a comment use #, """, or '''
asterisk will result in error